# Is this javascript syntax is correct? Node,js throws a syntax error

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
 if (oldPresenter?.userId !== currentPresenterId) {
      return setPresenterInPodReqMsg(setPresenterPayload);
    }
```

I got syntax error in this snippet running with Node.js but working for other people. I need explanation if it is correct JS syntax.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: Put it in your question, please. And be specific. Errors usually point to a specific line or character.

Comment: Probably you aren't running a new enough version of nodejs to support the `?.` feature.

Comment: You need node 14 or greater to use the safe navigation/chaining operator

Answer (score 2):

You are using optional chaining. It is in Stage 4.
Optional chaining is supported in node version v14.2.0 or higher!

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is the reference for the operator with browser compatibility, for those interested. I wasn't aware it's in development!

Answer (score 1):

`?.` is called the optional chaining operator. On the last versions of node it's valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This javascript syntax will be reported incorrect for any Node version < 14. To be able to use this format ( specifically the `?.` optional chaining syntax ), first check your node version using `node -v` on your commandline, and if < 14, then update to a Node version >=14.